# weblogic error while running the mvn antrun:run from app-ear module

Tags: java, maven, weblogic12c

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building WebLogic app ear 1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default-cli) @ app-ear ---
    [INFO] Executing tasks

    deploy-weblogic:
         [java]
         [java] Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
         [java]
         [java] Problem invoking WLST - java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\snapshotviews\app-snapshotviews\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\targWelcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
         [java]
         [java] Type help() for help on available commands
         [java]
         [java] et\app7001.localhost.py (The system cannot find the file specified)
         [java] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
         [java] Java Result: 1
        [mkdir] Created dir: C:\snapshotviews\app-snapshotviews\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\deploy\app7001\servers\admin7001
         [java] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9810
         [java] <Apr 21, 2016 3:06:22 PM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.s
    ecurity.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true>
         [java] <Apr 21, 2016 3:06:22 PM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dwebl
    ogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true>
         [java] <Apr 21, 2016 3:06:22 PM CDT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 24.51-b03 from Oracle Corporation>
         [java]
         [java] C:\snapshotviews\app-snapshotviews\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\deploy\app7001\config\config.xml not found
         [java]
         [java] No config.xml was found.
         [java] Would you like the server to create a default configuration and boot? (y/n):
         [java] Please enter y, n
         [java]
         [java] No config.xml was found.
         [java] Would you like the server to create a default configuration and boot? (y/n):
         [java] Please enter y, n
         [java]
         [java] No config.xml was found.
         [java] Would you like the server to create a default configuration and boot? (y/n):
         [java] Please enter y, n
         [java] <Apr 21, 2016 3:06:23 PM CDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:
         [java]
         [java] There are 1 nested errors:
         [java]
         [java] weblogic.management.internal.InteractiveConfigurationException: C:\snapshotviews\app-snapshotviews\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\deploy\app7001\config\config.xml not found.
         [java] If you wish to have the server generate a default configuration file and boot, please re-execute your start command and respond to prompts or pass additional parameter of -Dweblogic.manage
    ment.GenerateDefaultConfig
         [java]     at weblogic.management.internal.DomainDirectoryService.ensureDomainExists(DomainDirectoryService.java:147)
         [java]     at weblogic.management.internal.DomainDirectoryService.start(DomainDirectoryService.java:73)
         [java]     at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)
         [java]     at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)
         [java]     at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:879)
         [java]     at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:566)
         [java]     at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:467)
         [java]     at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:71)
         [java]
         [java] >
         [java] <Apr 21, 2016 3:06:23 PM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED>
         [java] <Apr 21, 2016 3:06:23 PM CDT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down>
         [java] <Apr 21, 2016 3:06:23 PM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>
         [java] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
         [java] Java Result: -1
    [INFO] Executed tasks
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 6.756 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-21T15:06:24-05:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/308M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

weblogic error occured while running the mvn antrun:run from app-ear module, not be able to deploy and start the weblogic server with maven build. Can someone help me on this issue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you can check that the file `C:\snapshotviews\app-snapshotviews\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\deploy\app7001\config\config.xml` exists and has the correct permissions, as this seems like a simple file not found case. If you do want to create it, then try with that -Dweblogic.management.GenerateDefaultConfig command it recommends.

If it seems like the file exists on that path, check how maven is running--maybe it needs Administrator priviledges.